# Some files get "Static file referenced by handler not found"

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm deploying to google app engine with Python/Django.
I store css files and images in automatically created Cloud Storage.
I can read css files, but not images.

I think that the path is not wrong because the css file can be read. I think that it is due to the specifications of App Engine, but I do not know the detailed cause.
Please support me.

Of course it works fine locally. It is a situation where an error occurs only in production.

▼Version

Python 3.9.12

Django 4.1.1

▼Log（Cloud Storage）

`Static file referenced by handler not found: staticfiles/img/example.png/`

▼app.yaml

```
runtime: python39
instance_class: F1
env: standard
service: default

entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT config.wsgi:application

includes:
 - secrets/secret.yaml

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: staticfiles/
- url: /.*
  secure: always
  script: auto
```

▼folder

[image]

Comment: `staticfiles/img/example.png/` you have a trailing slash.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy Do you mean that you need to support slashes in app.yaml?

Comment: No, I mean file paths don't end in a slash, but yours does. Unless you are trying to access a __directory__ named `example.png`, your path is wrong.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy I see, thanks. Indeed, when I checked now, there was no slash at the end of the css file. Do you know what measures you need to take?

Comment: `Do you know what measures you need to take?` - Don't put a slash after your filename.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy Thank you, solved it. The problem was a description mistake in the html file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a typo in the HTML.

```
<img class="..." src={% static "img/example.png" %}/>
```

↓

```
<img class="..." src={% static "img/example.png" %} />
```

It seems that I forgot to put a space after the file name, so it could not be referenced correctly in GCS.